# JavaScript: backgroundImage isn't changing with onMouseOver

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, event-handling

I'm pretty new to JavaScript, and I'm trying to figure something out. I have a series of images within a table, and I'd like each image to display within a div element when you hover over one. The problem is, the code doesn't appear to be doing anything. I hover over the div element, and no changes are being made to the #bigdisplay element. If I replace the backgroundImage with a property such as color, it works completely fine. What am I doing wrong? This is the code for my div element.

```
<div id="image1" onmouseover="document.getElementById('bigdisplay').style.backgroundImage='url('images/Slideshow1.png')';">
/* ... */
</div>
```

If I must provide any other code from my site I will (although I don't believe any of it is relevant). Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine.  I separated the js just to make it easier to read.  Your problem is either you have no height to the div or your path is wrong

```js
function test(){ document.getElementById('bigdisplay').style.backgroundImage=
'url("https://res.cloudinary.com/rss81/image/upload/gw.jpg")'}
```

```css
html,body,div{
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="bigdisplay" onmouseover="test()">
test
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not properly escaping the string in the attribute. Attach the listener in Javascript instead, rather than in HTML attributes (which is as bad as `eval`) and it'll be easier to read and write:

```
const bigdisplay = document.querySelector('#bigdisplay');
document.querySelector('#image1').addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  bigdisplay.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/Slideshow1.png')";
});
```

Comment: Or, y'know... use CSS since that's what it's for and nothing about this code is actually dynamic.

Comment: I don't think you use a selector on one element to affect an arbitrary element somewhere else in the DOM, outside of some special cases

Answer (score 0):

I think one problem is that you used single quote to quote 'images/Slideshow1.png'. But you used single quote also for 'url('images/Slideshow1.png')'. So there is a conflict. Try 'url("images/Slideshow1.png")'. A part for this I find better to define the event handler function in the js document linked to the html document.